# Presenting a modal view controller without covering the current view on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios7, childviewcontroller

[image]

I have been trying to add view container with leaving 20px space from the sides. But it seems not the proper way of doing it...

```
// ADD CHILD VIEW CONTROLLER
    [parentViewController addChildViewController:childViewController];
    [parentViewController.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
    [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:parentViewController];

// REMOVE THE CHILD VIEW CONTROLLER
    [childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [childViewController view] removeFromSuperview];
    [childViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

**UPDATE**
I have figured it out by using this MZFormSheetController "https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController" Form presentation with cool view transitions.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning "MZFormSheetController" !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **MZFormSheetController** "https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController" Form presentation with cool view transitions. 
Or, iOS 8 and above, you can use `viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;`
Good luck, let me know if you want a full snippet...

Answer (score 4):

You can try Something like,

```
DetailViewController *viewController= [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
viewController.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{
    viewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 500);
    viewController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
}];
```

Set `superview.frame` and `modalTransitionStyle` according to you.

Comment: It shows black background when I present the viewController. And I think UIModalPresentationFormSheet is available on iPad only!

Comment: After iOS 8 you can do viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to have your own controller and view.

On the main controller use the present view controller.

```
[self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

On the viewDidLoad adjust myController frame.

```
CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
newFame.size.width -= 40;
newFame.size.height -= 40;
newFrame.origin.x = 20;
newFrame.origin.y = 20;
self.view.frame = newFrame
```

---

Adding as childViewController is for view controller containment, when you want a single controller with multiples views, each with its own controller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Answer (score 1):

You're on a right way. But you have to add container view permanently on a storyboard, then you can just show/hide it by `setHidden:` method.

Also you can show second controller animated by this method.

Comment: you are right but it won't be as proper as this app has it... I am sure there is code somewhere for presenting UIModalPresentationFormSheet on iPhone

Comment: @MazenKasser `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` is working only on iPad. You have to read UI guidelines for iOS, an book written by Apple. I think you didn't yet. Even if you find such method, Apple will restrict you app, because it is not accomplish wish UI guidelines.

Comment: everything is possible, there are heaps of 3rd party libraries that customise Apples' APIs. Relax Apple won't reject the App for such thing... btw I have read that book since 2009, son you should catch up

Comment: @MazenKasser we was talking about `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` in iPhone, am i right? Relax father I've just said that Apple restricts app event if you find a way to use `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` at iPhone. There were no words about 3rd-party implementations.

Answer (score 0):

1. On iPhone and iPod touch, the presented view is always full screen. So, it can't be presenting a non-full screen view controller.
2. Don't presenting the view controller, add the view controller's view as a subview to the parent view controller. So, you can control the appearance, even the shadow layer under it.

Comment: the concept is correct but the code doesn't work as expected. First the child view goes under the navigationController of the root view controller, so I had to hide it and add a navigation bar... I think I should stick to my own code for now... thanks anyways